# Creating a datetime with year and month as inputs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a datetime with a value like:

```
2019-09-01 00:00:00.000
```

I have the values for year and month in variables @year and @month.

What is the best way to create a datetime with inputs?

Comment: Depends on the SQL Server version. Add the version-specific tag.

Comment: Are the variables numeric or strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
declare @year int = 2019
    , @month int = 9

SELECT convert(datetime, DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm include a @Day part too, as you may find it useful. If you do not want it, replace `RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(@Day),2)` with `'01'`

```
    DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(4) = '2019';
    DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(2) = '09'
    DECLARE @Day VARCHAR(2) = '01'

    SELECT CAST(CAST(@Year as char(4)) 
    + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(@Month),2) 
    + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(@Day),2) 
    AS Datetime)
```